# How to configure VS Code auto-imports in Sveltekit to avoid curly braces?

Tags: sveltekit, sveltekit-autoimport

Using VS Code with Sveltekit, I see intellisense suggesting auto imports with relative paths. When an import selected, it adds it correctly: `import  Accordion  from '$lib/components/Accordion.svelte';`

I then wanted VS Code to respect the `$lib` alias, which is defined by default by SvelteKit. It wasn't hapenning out of the box, so I added:

```
"paths": {
   "$lib": ["./src/lib"],
   "$lib/*": ["./src/lib/*"]
}
```

to `tsconfig.json`

After this, intellisense does suggest `$lib/components/Accordion.svelte`, which is the desired behavior. But when selected, it adds the import with curly braces around the component name: `import { Accordion } from '$lib/components/Accordion.svelte`, which results in the `Module has no exported member` error.

How can I get auto-import to import without curly braces where relevant?